# Is it possible to gather the number of bluetooth devices around Android device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I would like to get the number of bluetooth devices located around an android device and then store that number in the SQLite database. Is it possible to easily get that number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of discoverable devices and simply use the size() method to determine how many there are. The process of detecting discoverable devices is described here:

[Bluetooth | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html)

Comment: Also note that the relevant sections of that page are the sections up to and including "Finding Devices". You don't actually need to connect to those devices in order to get basic information about them.